# React keys for static array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Inside a React component I need to transform an array of objects into a specific HTML markup, using objects values as class names and building a couple of `span` tags, like this:

```js
const renderedText = () => {
  return text.map(e =>
    <>
      <span className={"text-"+e.player}>{e.text} </span>
      <span className={"snippet-"+e.player}>{e.snippet} </span>
    </>
)}

/// Returning this from the component
<div>{renderedText()}</div>
```

The result is exactly what I need, but how can I avoid the "unique key prop" warning? The HTML elements I'd like to render are completely static, they are never moved nor deleted. I'm just trying to build a long string of `span` items.

I tried this, which seems completely over the top and doesn't even get rid of the warning:

```js
const renderedText = () => {
  return text.map((e, index) =>
    <>
      <span key={"t" + index.toString()} className={"text-"+e.player}>{e.text} </span>
      <span key={"s" + index.toString()} className={"snippet-"+e.player}>{e.snippet} </span>
    </>
  )}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the key to the fragment instead.

```
...
  <React.Fragment key={key}>
    ...
  </React.Fragment>
```

Reference:

1. https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment#rendering-a-list-of-fragments